# How do I unlock more Infiltration Tools?

Tags: persona-5

While reading up on how/where to find the upper tier Treasure Demons, I came across mention of an Infiltration Tool called "Treasure Trap". However, I've completed the game and only ever saw the option to create the Lockpick, Eternal Lockpick, Stealthanol, and Covertizer. Where do I unlock the other Infiltration Tools like Treasure Trap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some tools are not available by default, such as the infinite-use lockpick. You will automatically unlock the recipe for all Infiltration Tools upon reaching Confidant rank 6 with [Morgana](http://megamitensei.wikia.com/wiki/Morgana), which unlocks the skill "Ace Tools", on

> 7/25.

However, despite completing the game, I was completely unaware of the different pages of Infiltration Tools. Based on posts like [this one](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/835628-persona-5/75253262), I am apparently not alone.

> Are you pressing R1 and L1 to cycle the menus? I didn't notice you could do that until like 2/3 of the way through the game x-x
>
> I played through this entire game. 115 hours. Two weeks. And I never once noticed.

Based on the list of Tools by type [here](http://www.neoseeker.com/persona-5/Infiltration_Tools), the default page shown to you is the Palace type of Infiltration Tool, but there are two other pages that have 11 more recipes, including Treasure Trap.